# jsf 2.0 f:ajax render ID not found

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, render

When the Save button in the popup(pp1) clicked the projects list gets updated.
But when press the update button in the projects list, the render ID :form1:pp1 is not there error comes when its being rendered. If do render="@all" it works, but its not good. 
( error : `<f:ajax>` contains an unknown id ':form1:pp1')

```
<h:form id="form1" prependid=false>
<h:panelGroup id="projects">
<ui:repeat var="action" value="#{dadadada}" varStatus="status">
<h:commandButton value="Save">
//gives id not found error
<f:ajax event="click" execute="@form" render=":form1:pp1" listener="#{fsfsfsfsfs}" />
</h:commandButton>
</ui:repeat>

</h:panelGroup> // project panel group

//popup
<h:panelGroup id="pp1">
<div id="popup2" class="popup_block">

//save button in the popup
<div class="popupBody_save2">
            <h:commandButton  image="resources/images/saveBtn.gif" value="Save">
             <f:ajax event="click" execute="@form" render="projects" listener="#{dfsfssfs}" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </div>

</div>
</h:panelGroup>

</h:form>
```

Answer (score 6):

The `:form1:pp1` won't work since you have `prependId="false"` on the form. The `pp1` won't work since it's then looking for the component in the same scope as `<ui:repeat>` which is by itself an `UINamingContainer` component.

Open the JSF page in webbrowser, rightclick and *View Source* to get the generated HTML. Locate the HTML element which is generated by `<h:panelGroup id="pp1">`. It should look something like this

```
<span id="foo:bar:pp1">
```

You need to use **exactly** this ID prefixed with `:` in the `render` attribute.

```
<f:ajax render=":foo:bar:pp1">
```

If there's an autogenerated ID part such as `j_id0`, then you need to give the parent component in question an fixed ID.

Comment: as prependId= false, it displays as `<span id="pp1">` which I should be able to access using render = ":pp1" isn't it? but id still can't find the element

Answer (score 0):

If you use `prependId=false` your panelGroup's id is `pp1` instead of `form1:pp1`. (Assume there is a typo in your attribute "prependID" instead of "prependid")

Comment: Look in the generated html source and try to find out what's the real id of your panelGroup.