# access to a ui component in primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Hello I'm new to PrimeFaces and I have for example a JSF page that contains many elements referenced by id like in

```
<p:panelGroup id="container">
    <h:form id="form1">
        <div id="div1">
        ...
        ...
    </h:form>
<p:commandButton action="#{bean.action}" value="update div1"  />
   ...
```

So how can I update the content of the `div1` or how can I access the compenent by its id?

In general I think there is something like this: `update=":container:form1:div1"` but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSF is a component-based framework and PrimeFaces is a component library on top of JSF aimed to provide for a wider range of components on top of standard JSF ones. There are plenty of components within both of them. For instance, `<p:panelGroup>` from PrimeFaces and `<h:form>` from JSF are the ones noted in your question. Every component has its unique id either preset via `id="component-id"`, or autogenerated if `id` attribute is omitted.

During the JSF lifecycle component tree is created that starts with `UIViewRoot` and then it is inhabited by the nested structure of components. As (most typically) you work with Facelets to declare the component structure, the contents of your Facelet will get the corresponding place in the component tree. That is, all of the referenced tags (like `<p:commandButton>` etc.) will become eventually `UIComponent` instances within the JSF component tree.

All of the residual tags (like HTML `<div>` etc.) will be interpreted as plain text, given that your file complies with all the restrictions on XHTML files. As soon as JSF will render the response those plain text will be written to the response as-is, without modifications. Remember, JSF is in the end the HTML code generator. Moreover, they won't have any corresponding instance in the component tree in contrast to the JSF components that have a unique id.

It's also worth noting the difference between the `id` attribute of a JSF component and its `clientId` that gets rendered to the response. For more information read on `UINamingContainer` that prepend id of its children.

Next, the contents of the component can be (re)rendered via AJAX. For this you need to pass the ids of components to be (re)rendered in `<p:commandButton>`'s `update` attribute. There are some nuances on how the to-be-rendered components are found via ids and these can differ from one component library to the other one. For the basic JSF rules read the classics: [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentOutsideForm) to get the grasp.

Ultimately, from the abovementioned you can devise a way out:

1. If you want to rerender something switch from HTML elements to pure JSF components that, in your case would work as containers, like `<h:panelGroup id="renderme">` that will also get rendered as `<div>`. This component can wrap the block you initially wanted to rerender. From now on, JSF will be able to find the component and rerender it;
2. Specify the [right id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5949114/1820286) for the to-be-rerendered component in `update` attribute of your command button, in your case `update=":container:form1:renderme"`.

Given this, your view will be like:

```
<p:panelGroup id="container">
    <h:form id="form1">
        <p:panelGroup id="renderme">
            <div id="div1">
                ...
            </div>
        </p:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
</p:panelGroup>
<p:commandButton action="#{bean.action}" value="update renderme" update=":container:form1:renderme" />
```